# Why does an equality check, not allow for implicit conversion of object types, but does for int?

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

Why does C# allow for the implicit conversion of an object to an int for equality comparison, but not for an object type to object type comparison, even though an implicit operator exists?

The `bool errorHere = valueOnly == valuePair;` line gives the exception at the bottom.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ValueOnly valueOnly = new ValueOnly();
        ValuePair valuePair = new ValuePair();
        bool areEqual = valueOnly.Value == valuePair;
        bool errorHere = valueOnly == valuePair;
        bool butNotHere = valueOnly == (ValueOnly)valuePair;
        valueOnly = valuePair; // Or Here
    }
}

public class ValuePair
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator ValueOnly(ValuePair valuePair) {
        if (valuePair.Text != null || valuePair.Value != 0) {
            return new ValueOnly() { Value = valuePair.Value };
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static implicit operator int(ValuePair valuePair) {
        return valuePair.Value;
    }
}

public class ValueOnly
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Error   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ValueOnly' and 'ValuePair'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# most certainly does not allow implicit conversions of objects to `int`s for any purpose. I 'm not sure if you are referring to the line

```
bool butNotHere = valueOnly == (ValueOnly)valuePair;
```

as "allowing" such a conversion. If so, it does not do any such thing. It simply invokes your own conversion operator (which if I read the code correctly will return `null` since the value will be a default-constructed integer) and then does a reference comparison between the two objects (which evaluates to `false` as `null` is not reference-equal to anything).

It also goes without saying that once you define an implicit conversion operator C# will use it whenever it is necessary. Therefore I think your question has to do more with understanding how the equality operator works based on the types of its arguments than anything else.

**Update, regarding the `valueOnly == valuePair` check:**

The C# specification, 7.10.6 (Reference type equality operators) states:

> It is a binding-time error to use the predefined reference type
>   equality operators to compare two references that are known to be
>   different at binding-time. For example, if the binding-time types of
>   the operands are two class types A and B, and if neither A nor B
>   derives from the other, then it would be impossible for the two
>   operands to reference the same object. Thus, the operation is
>   considered a binding-time error.

If you want to be able to compare objects of class type for equality, the best way is to implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface, and override `object.Equals` to be implemented in terms of `IEquatable<T>.Equals` (this means that you will also have to override `object.GetHashCode`) to match.

However, it's a bad idea to rely on "hidden" conversions when comparing items. If we 're talking about comparing unrelated classes, you will save yourself a lot of anguish down the road by making the comparison as prominent as possible. To that end, I would suggest the low tech

```
if(valuePair.Value == valueOnly.Value)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm saying it wrong, but if so, why does this work?  "bool areEqual = valueOnly.Value == valuePair;"  The Value property on valueOnly is an int, and the valuePair is implicitly being converted to an int...

Comment: The line you reference is performing an explicit conversion, using the defined implicit operator.  I guess the real question is, why do I have to explicitly define the conversion?

Comment: @Daryl: Revised after reading your question again. You have to explicitly define the conversion to `ValueOnly` from `ValuePair` because the two types are unrelated.

Comment: Not sure what unrelated means, how are int and ValuePair related?

Comment: @Daryl: Unrelated === not in an inheritance hierarchy. Where do you get the idea that `int` and `ValuePair` *are* related? (they are not)

Comment: I know they are not, but I don't understand why C# will use the implicit operator for ValuePair to int when doing an int to ValuePair comparison, but will not wuse the implicit operator for ValuePair to ValueOnly when doing a ValueOnly to ValuePair comparison...

Comment: @Daryl: [C# specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx), 7.10.6 (Reference type equality operators): *"It is a binding-time error to use the predefined reference type equality operators to compare two references that are known to be different at binding-time. For example, if the binding-time types of the operands are two class types A and B, and if neither A nor B derives from the other, then it would be impossible for the two operands to reference the same object. Thus, the operation is considered a binding-time error."*

Comment: Ah, I see!  Thanks.  Basically if I want the functionality, I'll have to declare applicable operator == and operator != members because the == operator ignores any implicit operations, as per the C# specifications!  I'm marking this as the answer, but you may want to promote your C# specification reference from a comment to the answer.

Comment: @Daryl: Updated question, please have a look. I think you may be starting down the wrong road here, and what you want to do is better done without any comparison functions. Also *avoid overriding the equality operator*. There are almost always more suitable ways to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

To allow valueOnly == valuePair you have to add this to the ValuePair class:

```
public static bool operator == (ValueOnly valueOnly, ValuePair valuePair){
    ValueOnly value = valuePair;
    return valueOnly.Value == value.Value;
}
```

This uses the implicit conversion, and then performs the equality check I'm looking for...

And now that I think of it, the implicit conversion is dumb (since I haven't provided an equality operator for the ValueOnly class):

```
public static bool operator == (ValueOnly valueOnly, ValuePair valuePair){
    return valueOnly.Value == valuePair.Value;
}
```